# Is there a reason for getting the Sceptre resolver error?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, localstack, sceptre

I am running into an error while deploying an application to Cloudformation

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sceptre.resolvers.join'

I tried to delete my local stack using Sceptre. I am trying to deploy my local stack with resources defined in a YAML file. But when I try to deploy the application to Cloudformation I get an error stating

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sceptre.resolvers.join'

I am using Sceptre 2. It seems while adding YAML constructors, resolvers are not getting hooked in as an entry point.